# Angular-cli aot build fails in production mode

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

> ERROR in Child compilation failed: Module build failed: TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
>       at Object.getNewLineCharacter (C:...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9581:20)
>       at Object.createCompilerHost (C:...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:66675:26)
>       at Object.ngcLoader (C:...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:386:33): TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:...\src'  @ ./src/main.ts
>   2:0-74  @ multi ./src/main.ts
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "ng" "build"
>   "--" "--prod" npm ERR! node v6.10.3 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! fol-mcdean@0.1.0 ng: `ng "build" "--prod"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   fol-mcdean@0.1.0 ng script 'ng "build" "--prod"'. npm ERR! Make sure
>   you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If
>   you do, this is most likely a problem with the fol-mcdean package, npm
>   ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on
>   your system: npm ERR!     ng "build" "--prod" npm ERR! You can get
>   information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!
>   npm bugs fol-mcdean npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get
>   their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls fol-mcdean npm ERR! There is
>   likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:...\npm-debug.log

I have a project with this, using @angular 4.1.3 and @angular/cli 1.1.0-rc.0 (tried 1.04 as well with the same result). So the project builds fine with
ng build --aot=true
but fails with this error using ng build --prod.

I did some debugging of \node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js

And it turns out it breaks on these lines:

```
function ngcLoader() { 
...
const sourceFileName = this.resourcePath; //here is index.ts file, I'll show it later
const plugin = this._compilation._ngToolsWebpackPluginInstance; //plugin === undefined here!
if (plugin && plugin instanceof plugin_1.AotPlugin) { //and of course this is false
...
} else {
const options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this) || {}; //and options are {} here...
...
const compilerHost = ts.createCompilerHost(compilerOptions); //and of cource it breaks here
...
}
}
```

And the file on which it fails is index.ts:

```
export * from './GJLog.component';
```

I've also checked all the versions of all packages, cleaned cache, reinstalled node.. Everything.. But still the same problem in AOT mode. In the same time, it perfectly compiles with aot=false...

Then I've decided to read what's the difference between --prod and not --prod:
And ran the following command:

```
npm run ng build -- --aot=true --environment=prod --output-hashing=all --sourcemaps=false --extract-css=true
```

**And it worked!**

So, remaining is this:

> --prod also sets the following non-flaggable settings:
>
> 1) Adds service worker if configured in .angular-cli.json.
>
> 2) Replaces process.env.NODE_ENV in modules with the production value (this is needed for some libraries, like react).
>
> 3) Runs UglifyJS on the code

So I don't have any service workers, and process.env.NODE_ENV is not applicable either...
So is this UglifyJS? 
Not sure what to do next. Any suggestions?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3985

Comment: Nope. It did not work. I've tried all things with reinstalling/cleaning / resetting npm caches. Its not the case...

Comment: Then I'd suggest to open an issue at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Will do...  Hope they'll answer something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution and investigation to the problem is here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6426

In general seems the reason was in cssnano and an empty url("").